# On jqgrid next button click, data is not being populated

Tags: jqgrid, pager

I am using onPaging event and doing some back-end logic on it and sending json back to jsp page.
e.g. I have 10 records in my grid, and rownum is 2. that means i have 5 pages to display.
on click of next button no. of pages displayed is changed (2/5) but data shows first 2 records only.

I am getting "page" in json object string:

```
{"page":2,"records":9,"rowNum":2,...}
```

but the records visible on page 2 are same as it was on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

If jqGrid will ask the server to get the second page you should include in the JSON data **only two rows**: the records with the ordinal numbers 3 and 4:

```
{
    "total": 5,
    "page": "2",
    "records": "10",
    "rows": [
        { "id": "id of the record 3", "cell": [...] },
        { "id": "id of the record 4", "cell": [...] }
    ]
}
```

If you use another data format you should nevertheless include only information about the second page in the server response.

Comment: I want to add all records in json object, otherwise i can not see prev/first records on click of "Prev" and "first" buttons.